# Disable keyboard regedit on Windows CE handheld not working

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-ce, boot, regedit

I'm trying to disable the automatic keyboard pop up as soon as you enter an input field on a handheld, operating Windows CE.

It works by setting the key value "TurnOffAutoDeploy" to "1".

I created this regedit script:

`REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\Sip]
"TurnOffAutoDeploy"="1"`

I copied the file into the "Application" folder, in order to load up my script automatically, which changes the keyvalue after a cold boot.

**Problem:**
After a cold boot the keyboard still pops up after entering an input field.
I checked the registry again and the key is changed to "1", just as I wanted.
Seems like it doesn't affect anything. I tried many other things, i.e. changing the "Disabled" and "AllowChange". NOT working.

Have you ever experienced this?

I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is stuck on this problem, this is the solution.
Use this reg script:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ControlPanel\SIP]
"TurnOffAutoDeploy"=dword:1
```

And copy your file to the Application/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is an other way. You can go to ControlPanel -> DataLogic Desktop Utility -> "Win" tab -> uncheck "Auto sip"

With this, virtual keyboard is completly disable.